# Reach the div of my router-outlet when I click on the navigation bar in the app.component in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have my app.component page and i want when i click to my navigation bar i reach this div particular div **()**

app.component

```
<div class="navigation">
  <div id="navigation">
  <ul>
  <li class="active"><a [routerLink]="['/accueil']" >Accueil</a></li>
  <li><a  routerLink ="apropos" >A propos de nous</a> </li>
  <li class="has-sub"><a [routerLink]="" >Payer</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a [routerLink]="['/payer/nat']" >Vol national</a></li>
          <li><a [routerLink]="['/payer/int']" >Vol international</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a routerLink="temoin" >Temoignages</a>
      <li><a routerLink="contact">Contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="space-medium">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

I want to have this behaviour

1. click on "Accueil", I go to **div class="space-medium"**
2. click on "A propos de nous", I go to **div class="space-medium"**
3. click on "Payer", I go to **div class="space-medium"**
4. click on "Vol national", I go to **div class="space-medium"**
5. click on "Vol international", I go to **div class="space-medium"**
6. click on "Temoignages", I go to **div class="space-medium"**
7. click on "contact", I go to **div class="space-medium"**

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor link, see how angular doc page does it.

guide/forms is the component route. #build-a-template-driven-form is where the div(any html elements)  is.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Xie Dongfeng, can you give me an example with my code and the angular doc link about this.